# Jquery sortable 'change' event element position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there way to get current position of helper being dragged on over new position ?

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var currPos1 = ui.item.index();
        },
        change:  function (event, ui) {
            var currPos2 = ui.item.index();
        }
});
```

It seems that currPos1 and currPos2 have same value when actual change happens !

What I need to achieve is highlight to user all positions between 'start drag element' to 'currently replaced element'. Once user releases mouse button update happens and only then I get new position, but I need it before mouse release.

Comment: i have updated the code once again. try the demo and let me know.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

### UPDATED: 26/08/2016 <sup>to use the latest jquery and jquery ui version plus bootstrap to style it.</sup>

> - **demo:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-sortable-change-event-element-position/

```
$(function() {
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var start_pos = ui.item.index();
            ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
            var index = ui.placeholder.index();
            if (start_pos < index) {
                $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('highlights');
            } else {
                $('#sortable li:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('highlights');
            }
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            $('#sortable li').removeClass('highlights');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I saw that question. It works with 'update' event but I need current position in 'change' event!

Comment: var index = ui.placeholder.index() is what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: I had an issue with this code, In your example, if you moves an element to get some elements highlighted, and then return it to it's original position, the highlights still stands, even you drop it.

Comment: I changed the last function from **update** to **stop**, so even the final position is the original it will remove the highlights

Comment: I'm using code like this but i have problem with dynamically added element, they can't trigger events and I confused how could I do that?

Comment: @QMaster: i have updated my demo to use the latest jquery and jquery ui version plus bootstrap to style it. if you are using an older version check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660606/jquery-ui-draggable-and-dynamic-jquery-ui-draggable

Comment: @LucaFilosofi Thanks, but I'm using new version of jQuery and about bootstrap I didn't use it because of using my own styles, I found my problem, I need to repeat above jQuery function after adding new dynamic element to sortable, Thanks again.

Answer (score 19):

This works for me:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
update: function (event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
        var end_pos = ui.item.index();
        //$('#sortable li').removeClass('highlights');
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `update`, `stop` and `receive` events, check it over here

[Jquery Sortable Update Event can called only one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101129/jquery-sortable-update-event-can-called-only-one-time/8896191#8896191)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested in a sortable list with a changing index per listitem (1st, 2nd, 3th etc...:

http://jsfiddle.net/aph0c1rL/1/

```
$(".sortable").sortable(
{
  handle:         '.handle'
, placeholder:    'sort-placeholder'
, forcePlaceholderSize: true
, start: function( e, ui )
{
    ui.item.data( 'start-pos', ui.item.index()+1 );
}
, change: function( e, ui )
  {
      var seq
      , startPos = ui.item.data( 'start-pos' )
      , $index
      , correction
      ;

      // if startPos < placeholder pos, we go from top to bottom
      // else startPos > placeholder pos, we go from bottom to top and we need to correct the index with +1
      //
      correction = startPos <= ui.placeholder.index() ? 0 : 1;

      ui.item.parent().find( 'li.prize').each( function( idx, el )
      {
        var $this = $( el )
        , $index = $this.index()
        ;

        // correction 0 means moving top to bottom, correction 1 means bottom to top
        //
        if ( ( $index+1 >= startPos && correction === 0) || ($index+1 <= startPos && correction === 1 ) )
        {
          $index = $index + correction;
          $this.find( '.ordinal-position').text( $index + ordinalSuffix( $index ) );
        }

      });

      // handle dragged item separatelly
      seq = ui.item.parent().find( 'li.sort-placeholder').index() + correction;
      ui.item.find( '.ordinal-position' ).text( seq + ordinalSuffix( seq ) );
} );

// this function adds the correct ordinal suffix to the provide number
function ordinalSuffix( number )
{
  var suffix = '';

  if ( number / 10 % 10 === 1 )
  {
    suffix = "th";
  }
  else if ( number > 0 )
  {

    switch( number % 10 )
    {
      case 1:
        suffix = "st";
        break;
      case 2:
        suffix = "nd";
        break;
      case 3:
        suffix = "rd";
        break;
      default:
        suffix = "th";
        break;
    }
  }
  return suffix;
}
```

Your markup can look like this:

```
<ul class="sortable ">
<li >        
    <div>
        <span class="ordinal-position">1st</span>
         A header
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="icon-button handle"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bpdy" >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    </div>
</li>
 <li >        
    <div>
        <span class="ordinal-position">2nd</span>
         A header
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="icon-button handle"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bpdy" >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    </div>
</li>
etc....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    change: function(event, ui) {       
        var pos = ui.helper.index() < ui.placeholder.index() 
            ? { start: ui.helper.index(), end: ui.placeholder.index() }
            : { start: ui.placeholder.index(), end: ui.helper.index() }

        $(this)
            .children().removeClass( 'highlight' )
            .not( ui.helper ).slice( pos.start, pos.end ).addClass( 'highlight' );
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).children().removeClass( 'highlight' );
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfsc6/)

An example of how it could be done inside change event without storing arbitrary data into element storage. Since the element where drag starts is `ui.helper`, and the element of current position is `ui.placeholder`, we can take the elements between those two indexes and highlight them. Also, we can use `this` inside handler since it refers to the element that the widget is attached. The example works with dragging in both directions.