# Jquery Create Dynmica draggable elements by value in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jquery to dynamically create a set of draggable `div's` that contain input fields with a numeric label and a option to edit the label.

The user will enter the number of  `div's`  they want and hit create. I dont want the `div's` to appear on page load, instead i want the user to request the amount of  `div's"` and then the button creates them.

I can create the  `div's` dynamically but i lose the ability to drag. I also want to remove the  `div's`  on page load. They should only appear after the user submits a request.

Check out what i have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/kocwtg0b/

```
 # <input type="text" id="num" name="more" value=''>
 <button type="button" id="more" name="more">Create</button
 <br>
 <br>
 <div class="container" id="inputcontainer">
<div class="bl blue draggable"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="bl coral draggable"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="bl pink draggable"><input type="text" /></div>
 </div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

$('.container').on('click', '.pink', function () {
    $("<div class='bl pink'></div>").appendTo('.container').draggable();
});

$('.container').on('click', '.blue', function () {
    $("<div class='bl blue'></div>").appendTo('.container').draggable();
});
$('.container').on('click', '.coral', function () {
    $("<div class='bl coral'></div>").appendTo('.container').draggable();
});

$(".draggable").draggable();


 });

 function createMore(){
var num = $('#num').val();
for( var i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
    $("#inputcontainer").append("<div class='bl blue draggable'></div>");

}
 }
 $("#more").click(".add",createMore);
 </script>


<style>
html, body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
.container {
margin:20px;
}
.bl {
width:200px;
height:200px;
border-radius:10px;
display:block;
margin:5px;
float:left;
}
.pink {
background-color:#D91C5C;
}
.blue {
background-color:#00ADEE;
}
.coral {
background-color:#EE4036;
}
</style>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kocwtg0b/1/ According to this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660606/jquery-ui-draggable-and-dynamic-jquery-ui-draggable