# Not able to drag appended items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to make an appended item draggable using jquery ui, With jquery I'm trying to say when a veggie is clicked add it to the dirt.
make the veggies draggable in the dirt but be constrained within that element. Is there a reason the following code isn't working?

```
<body>
  <ul id = "dirt">  
  </ul>    
  <ul id = "veggies">
    <li class ="veg tomato"></li>
    <li class ="veg cucumber"></li>
    <li class ="veg pepper"></li>
    <li class ="veg eggplant"></li>
    <li class ="veg beans"></li>
  </ul>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#veggies li").click(function(){
    $(this).clone().appendTo("#dirt");
    });
  $("#dirt li").draggable({
    containment: '#dirt'
  });
}); 
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery-ui draggable and dynamic Jquery-ui draggable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660606/jquery-ui-draggable-and-dynamic-jquery-ui-draggable)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the element draggable AFTER you append it, as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5b3nfm11/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#veggies li").click(function(){
    $(this).clone().appendTo("#dirt").draggable({
      containment: '#dirt'
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I knew it had to be something so simple like that!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be making your #veggies list items draggable instead of appending them on click.

This ought to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#veggies li").draggable(function(){
  $(this).clone().appendTo("#dirt")
 });
});
```