# Detect if element position was changed in Jquery UI sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use the following code to reorder items on my website:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-list").sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');

            var url = '/en/account/changeposition?id=idreplace&position=posReplace';

            url = url.replace("idreplace", id);
            url = url.replace("posReplace", ui.item.index());

            window.location.href = url;
        },
        distance: 15
    });
});
```

However, even if I don't change element position and place element at the same place, Jquery UI will call 'stop'-function.

Is it possible to detect if element index (position) was changed without using custom data attributes?

```
// I would like to avoid adding custom data attributes like this:
<li id="id100" data-original-position="1"></li>
<li id="id101" data-original-position="2"></li>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4956452/875608).

It worked for me as follows:

```
$(selector).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.data('start_pos', ui.item.index());
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
        if (start_pos != ui.item.index()) {
            // the item got moved
        } else {
            // the item was returned to the same position
        }
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $.post('/reorder', $(selector).sortable('serialize'))
            .done(function() {
                alert('Updated')
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Unless I'm missing something, the `update` event would be your best option here. Per the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)

> This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

So if the only thing you're concerned about when the user stops dragging is whether or not the index changed, just use `update` and save yourself the trouble of setting and evaluating data properties.

Comment: I agree, I just needed the update portion. As soon as the sort is done then I just used the `id="xxx"` field I associated with the container `<div>`  serialized the array and updated my field in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

Got this from http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

> update( event, ui )Type: sortupdate
>   This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed

According to that, update is the only thing you need... becease update detects if the DOM position has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst using the update event appears to be the best answer for most scenarios, it's worth bearing in mind that this event does not trigger if the element hasn't moved.

Whilst this might be fine in most cases, you may need to run some code when sortable stops BUT no changes were made (I found myself needing to reset some global variables).  This was only possible using the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool

```
sortableChanged = false;
```

Set to `true` in the update of the `JQuery` sortable.