# In Struts 2, how can I update values from a TreeSet in my form?

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, struts2

I have a `TreeSet<Rule>` in my model which holds Rules and their hierarchical level - which need, by requirement, to be reorderable by the user. A Rule has the following model:

```
public class Rule {
    int id;
    int level;
    String desc;
}
```

I am trying to abstract the view from the model as much as possible, to avoid user errors. Being the fool that I am, I thought it would be "neat" to allow users to drag and drop rules to rearrange them - which is why I'm considering using JQuery's [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) element.

In my view, I'd display the rows which could be reordered by the user. I'd then update the level value from the Rules. My problem is: I need to update the level value of each Rule once the user clicks the Update button.

**Form**:

```
class RulesForm extends ActionForm {
  private TreeSet<Rule> rules;
  private int[] reorderedIds;
  // Getters and Setters
}
```

**View**:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable tr" ).sortable();
  $( "#sortable tr" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<html:form action="/rules?method=update">
<table>
  <c:forEach items="rule" var="rules">
    <tr class="sortable"><td id="${rule.id}">
      <bean:write name="rule" property="desc" />
    </td></tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
<html:submit value="Update"/>
```

1) How can I update each Rule's level? I am considering either:

- Using a change event that would interchange the $rule.level values using ui.item.index and ui.placeholder.index (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956039/jquery-sortable-change-event-element-position));
- Retrieving the list of ids (ex: `[1,4,3]`) and implementing a logic to reorder my TreeSet;
- Use jquery-cookie to hold the TreeSet;
- Forget it and change the view to something easier.

2) Once I've changed the rows positions, how can I retrieve them in my Form?

Comment: You can use `update` event to set some hidden fields and later submit them into action. Not sure about using `TreeSet` - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15006868/1700321.