# How to stop double callback when using jquery'Sortable's update event?

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I am building a sortable list using jquery Sortable only, and in that I am using `update` event to update sortorder in DB (by calling `UpdateSorderOrder`). The problem here is that the update event provides two callback to the `UpdateSorderOrder` function when items is move another list, but if item is sort in the same list it do one callback.

I can use `ui.sender == null` to stop double callback when moving item from one list to another, but it also stop updating DB if items are sorting in the same list.

So can anyone tell me which event to use in proper way so I can stop double event when item moves from one list to another and also provide callback to when items are sorted in the same list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer, use combination of `update`, `stop` and `receive` events, check it over here

[Jquery Sortable Update Event can called only one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101129/jquery-sortable-update-event-can-called-only-one-time/8896191#8896191)